# Should I use “me” or “myself” here?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, reflexives

I know that many questions on topics similar to this one have been asked before, but I have read many of them and still not able to solve my problem. You could attribute it to my poor command of English. My question relates to two weird sentences, and I want to know which sentence is correct:

> I am so hungry, it feels like my tummy is eating **myself**.

or

> I am so hungry, it feels like my tummy is eating **me**.

Comment: "My tummy" is not "me". _Myself_ can only occur as a direct object when the subject of the clause is _I_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reflexive pronouns (which end in *-self*) can only be used when the person or thing they refer to is the same as the subject in the clause where it appears.

In the clause in question here, the subject is *my tummy*, the verb is *is eating*, and the problematic pronoun at the end (the object) is *me/myself*.

If you use a pronoun instead of the noun phrase *my tummy*, it has to be *it*: “How is my tummy? *It* is hungry”. That means it is a pronoun in the third person—not the same as *me*, which is the first person.

Therefore, you cannot use the reflexive pronoun; it must be:

> I am so hungry it feels like my tummy is eating **me**.

If the object being eaten were not you as a person, but the tummy which is also doing the eating, a reflexive pronoun would be called for—but then it would not be *myself*, since the tummy is third person; it would have to be *itself*:

> I am so hungry it feels like my tummy is eating **itself**.